# Setting a USB camera in ROS

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera, uvc-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

First of all i wanna say that i'm really really new at ROS, I basiclly just started and so I don't know even all the commands and functionalities that there is. So I apolagize if I make really stupid questions.

I'm trying to use a USB camera, i have a HP HD 4310. I installed 'cheese' and ran it and could see the output from the camera, so i know the camera is linked just fine. After that i tried to install it in ROS, and that's where the problems started. After some research i followed some steps, and this like this:

`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-uvc-camera`

Afterwards also tried:

`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-cv-camera`

`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-libuvc-camera`

I also went to /dev and saw that my camera was in /dev/video1.

After that i tried to initialize the camera, by doing:

`rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node _device:=/dev/video1`

But i get the following messages:

```
[ INFO] [1506553332.714160099]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1506553332.714246140]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/cesar/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1506553332.714315848]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/cesar/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1506553332.714344759]: Camera calibration file /home/cesar/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
opening /dev/video1
pixfmt 0 = 'YUYV' desc = 'YUYV 4:2:2'
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 160x120:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 176x144:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 320x240:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 352x288:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 424x240:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 640x360:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 800x448:   1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 800x600:   1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 848x480:   1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 960x540:   1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 960x720:   1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 1280x720:   2/15 
  discrete: 1920x1080:   1/5 
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
pixfmt 1 = 'MJPG' desc = 'Motion-JPEG'
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 160x120:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 176x144:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 320x240:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 352x288:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 416x240:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 640x360:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 800x448:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 800x600:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 848x480:   1/30 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 960x544:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 960x720:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 1280x720:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 1920x1080:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/25 1/20 1/15 1/10 2/15 
  int (Brightness, 0, id = 980900): -64 to 64 (1)
  int (Contrast, 0, id = 980901): 0 to 50 (1)
  int (Saturation, 0, id = 980902): 0 to 100 (1)
  int (Hue, 0, id = 980903): -100 to 100 (1)
  bool (White Balance Temperature, Auto, 0, id = 98090c): 0 to 1 (1)
  int (Gamma, 0, id = 980910): 100 to 300 (1)
  menu (Power Line Frequency, 0, id = 980918): 0 to 2 (1)
    0: Disabled
    1: 50 Hz
    2: 60 Hz
  int (White Balance Temperature, 16, id = 98091a): 2800 to 6500 (10)
  int (Sharpness, 0, id = 98091b): 0 to 10 (1)
  int (Backlight Compensation, 0, id = 98091c): 0 to 1 (1)
  menu (Exposure, Auto, 0, id = 9a0901): 0 to 3 (1)
  int (Exposure (Absolute), 16, id = 9a0902): 5 to 10000 (1)
  int (Focus (absolute), 16, id = 9a090a): 0 to 56 (1)
  bool (Focus, Auto, 0, id = 9a090c): 0 to 1 (1)
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  couldn't dequeue buffer
 Aborted (image saved)
```

After this message a windows appears saying that the application uvc_camera finished unexpectedly.

What am i doing wrong guys? From what i read so far i think i need to do something with roslaunch and some launch files, but i can't find any and so I really don't know what to try.

I also went and check the list of nodes, by doing:

```
rosnode list
```

And in fact uvc_camera is one of them. Although when I do:

```
rosnode info /uvc_camera
```

This appears:

```
Node [/uvc_camera] 
Publications: 
 * /image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image]
 * /image_raw/theora [theora_image_transport/Packet]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /image_raw/compressed [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage]
 * /image_raw/compressedDepth [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage]
 * /image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /image_raw/theora/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo]
 * /image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]

Subscriptions: None

Services: 
 * /set_camera_info
 * /uvc_camera/get_loggers
 * /image_raw/compressed/set_parameters
 * /uvc_camera/set_logger_level
 * /image_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters
 * /image_raw/theora/set_parameters


contacting node http://cesar-X550JX:46532/ ...
ERROR: Communication with node[http://cesar-X550JX:46532/] failed!
```

As you can see there is some error in communicating with the node, i don't know why.

Sorry if this is very basic questions. But can someone give some guidence?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271685/setting-a-usb-camera-in-ros/) by [cesarPR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32044/cesarpr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-09-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-09-27**:
Try `rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node _device:=/dev/video1` (added `_` before device, since it's a private parameter and not topic)

**Comment by [cesarPR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32044/cesarpr/) on 2017-09-27**:
Hi @ahendrix, thanks for that observation, in fact that was something i was doing wrong. Please re read my post as i edited it with the new result after I corrected that

**Comment by [cesarPR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32044/cesarpr/) on 2017-09-28**:
@ahendrix, please check the new information that i added

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-09-28**:
It looks like you have the parameters right now, and the node is crashing. I don't know enough about the specifics of the uvc_camera node to know why it might be crashing.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-09-28**:
Try out http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam (`_video_device:=/dev/video1`, the parameters are named different)- it's possible with either package that the default pixel format doesn't work (perhaps to the point of crashing), and you should try the other ones.  Does /dev/video0 (your laptop camera?) work?

**Comment by [cesarPR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32044/cesarpr/) on 2017-09-29**:
How can i install that package usb_cam @lucasw ? That website on wiki only has the code on github. How do i install it?
If i try doing "rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node _device.=/dev/video0" gives the exact same messages.

**Comment by [cesarPR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32044/cesarpr/) on 2017-09-29**:
Another thing that i saw is that by doing "rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view" it only gives me the image of the internal pc camera, and not my USB camera. Although when i do "cheese" wich is a program to see streaming output from a camera it gives me the image of the usb camera..

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-09-29**:
If you can see the image in rqt_image_view that means the node is working?  Or does it only do a few frames then dies?  `/dev/video0` is likely your internal camera, and `/dev/video1` is what you plugged in - it is worth trying different cameras to see if the problem is with the camera or elsewhere.

**Comment by [cesarPR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32044/cesarpr/) on 2017-09-29**:
Hey, after i run the node on the camera that i plugged in, when i do rqt_image_view i can see the output from that camera. And doesn't die, is consistent

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-09-29**:
So `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'` isn't happening now, or infrequently, or it happens but the driver continues and works after that?

**Comment by [cesarPR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32044/cesarpr/) on 2017-09-29**:
Doesn't happen. I get no error.
I think the problem might be that i haven't calibrated the camera yet, i'll try and do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So i managed to get this working. The error was because i hadn't calibrated the camera yet, and so there was no calibration file on that path "/home/cesar/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml".

After i calibrated following http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration all started to work.

---

Originally posted by [cesarPR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32044/cesarpr/) with karma: 48 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0